# Find tensile force in the middle extensible cord

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

I came across the following question:

Three segments cut from a long elastic light cord are knotted at point $P$. The other ends of the cords are attached to the ceiling so that all the segments are in a vertical plane and the angle between outer and middle segments each being $ \theta $. A load of mass $m$ is suspended from the knot $P$. If extensions in the cords are negligible as compared to their relaxed lengths, find the tensile force $T$ developed in the middle cord. Acceleration due to gravity is $g$.

Now I know that the weight of the load will be balanced by the vertical components of the tensile forces. But in this context, I have no idea at all about how to find the tensile forces as the extensions of the cords are said to be negligible, so I don't know how Hooke's law comes into play here. Then, in the hint given it says that since the product of the force constant and length of a segment is constant, so the force constant of the middle cord is different from the outer cords'.

Please help me out with this problem.

The given answer is:
$$ \frac {mg} {1+ 2 \cos^3 \theta} $$

P.S: Are there any resources where I may learn more about such problems and the skills needed to solve them? Kindly recommend some.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This BEGS for a schematic diagram.

Comment: @Gert I added the diagram which was given in the book. Sorry if it's a little dark and shabby.

Comment: Thank you, it's quite clear.

Comment: This is actually a poorly defined problem, which doesn't have a 'unique' solution. That's because the central segment is really superfluous to requirement: a solution exists WITHOUT the central segment. It's not a problem for beginners.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your insight sir. Still, if there is any elementary solution you could give, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: It's a question of Degrees of Freedom. Right now you have one DoF too many. Solve that problem by withdrawing ONE of the three sections. Most 'logically' to maintain symmetry, the central one.

Comment: I think in the  answer there should be $\cos^2\theta$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it may appear to be a problem with too many degrees of freedom to solve, it actually isn't.

If the extensions are negligible, it means that in the new force equilibrium, you can assume that $\theta$ did not change significantly.

Define the length of the two outer ropes $L$. The weight of the mass will extend the center rope by an amount $\delta$ and the side ropes by an amount $\epsilon=\delta\cos(\theta)$ (using the approximation of negligible extension).

Assuming that the ropes are made of a the same material, the tension of the two side ropes are now $T_s=k\epsilon/L$ for the sides. The tension  of the center rope is different because of the different extension $\delta$ *and* because of the different length. Here $k$ is some constant depending on the properties of the rope. The total upward force from the three ropes must be equal to the weight $mg$. It turns out that you can eliminate the various unknowns ($L, \delta, \epsilon, k$).

Comment: Thanks sir! This was the solution I needed.

Comment: I think in the answer there should be $\cos^2\theta$